# Contained Query does not work in spatial coordinates in GeoDjango?

Tags: python, geodjango, django

These are my Models. I imported the shapefiles to this Models

```
class Parcel(models.Model):
    objectid = models.BigIntegerField()
    apn = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    lot_size = models.BigIntegerField()
    neibrhc = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    street_nbr = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    street_nam = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    zip = models.BigIntegerField()
    tra = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    subdivisio = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    lot = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    landuse = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    lu_general = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    lu_specif = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    lu_detail = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    lu_use = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    lu_sec_use = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    area = models.FloatField()
    perimeter = models.FloatField()
    shape_are = models.FloatField()
    shape_len = models.FloatField()
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid = 3492)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'City: %s' % self.city

class Primary(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 12, primary_key = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length = 13)
    primpgon = models.BigIntegerField()
    numpgons = models.BigIntegerField()
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    censusbloc = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    objectid = models.BigIntegerField()
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid = 4326)


from django.contrib.gis.geos
import Polygon
parcel = Parcel.objects.filter(objectid = "22520").values()
geojson = parcel[0]['geom'].geojson
format_l = ast.literal_eval(geojson)
coordinates_data = format_l['coordinates'][0][0]

poly = Polygon(coordinates_data, srid = 3492)
poly_parcel = poly.transform(4326, clone = True)
polygon = poly_parcel.coords
print(polygon)
```

I define the Polygon as below

```
(((-121.49440799279022, 38.55725848782723),
    (-121.49438844924772, 38.557303481514126),
    (-121.4943760310021, 38.5573320694682),
    (-121.49436263531841, 38.557362909896675),
    (-121.49402385986245, 38.557269114460084),
    (-121.49406987333441, 38.55716268909225),
    (-121.49440799279022, 38.55725848782723)), )
```

My Aim is I want to locate the Primary data within the Parcel Data. So I tried this.

```
    Primary.objects.filter(geom__contains=polygon).values()
    #and also tried with contained lookup
    Primary.objects.filter(geom__contained=polygon).values()
```

When I try this querysets it throws the **"ValueError: Cannot use object with type tuple for a spatial lookup parameter."**

I tried the with List also, but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def BuildingCoordinates(request):
        final_coordinates = []
        parcel = Parcel.objects.filter(objectid="22520").values()
        geojson = parcel[0]['geom'].geojson
        ast_format = ast.literal_eval(geojson)
        data = ast_format['coordinates'][0][0]
        poly_california = Polygon(data, srid=3492)
        poly_gps = poly_california.transform(4326, clone=True)
        pnt = GEOSGeometry(poly_gps)
        building = Primary.objects.filter(geom__contained=pnt).values()
        build_geo = building[0]['geom'].geojson
        build_format = ast.literal_eval(build_geo)
        build_coords = build_format['coordinates'][0]
        return HttpResponse(build_coords,content_type='application/json')
```